# Apache Nifi (on docker): only one of the HTTP and HTTPS connectors can be configured at one time error

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, apache-nifi

Have a problem adding authentication due to a new needs while using Apache NiFi (NiFi) without SSL processing it in a container.

The image version is `apache/nifi:1.13.0`

It's said that SSL is unconditionally required to add authentication. It's recommended to use `tls-toolkit` in the NiFi image to add SSL. Worked on the following process:

- Except for environment variable `nifi.web.http.port` for HTTP communication, and executed `up` the standalone mode container with `nifi.web.https.port=9443`

```sh
docker-compose up
```

- Joined to the container and run the tls-toolkit script in the nifi-toolkit.

```sh
cd /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-1.13.0/bin &&\
sh tls-toolkit.sh standalone \
  -n 'localhost' \
  -C 'CN=yangeok,OU=nifi' \
  -O -o $NIFI_HOME/conf
```

#### Attempt 1

- Organized files in directory `$NIFI_HOME/conf`. Three files `keystore.jks`, `truststore.jsk`, and `nifi.properties` were created in folder `localhost` that entered the value of the option `-n` of the tls-toolkit script.

```sh
cd $NIFI_HOME/conf &&
cp localhost/*.jks .
```

- The file `$NIFI_HOME/conf/localhost/nifi.properties` was not overwritten as it is, but only the following properties were imported as a file `$NIFI_HOME/conf/nifi.properties`:

  - `nifi.web.http.host=`
  - `nifi.web.http.port=`
  - `nifiweb.https.host=localhost`
  - `nifiweb.https.port=9443`
- Restarted container

```sh
docker-compose restart
```

- The container died with below error log:

> Only one of the HTTP and HTTPS connectors can be configured at one time

#### Attempt 2

- After executing the tls-toolkit script, all files a were overwritten, including file `nifi.properties`

```sh
cd $NIFI_HOME/conf &&
cp localhost/* .
```

- Restarted container

```sh
docker-compose restart
```

- The container died with the same error log

#### Hint

The dead container volume was also accessible, so copied and checked file `nifi.properties`, and when did `docker-compose up` or `restart`, it changed as follows:

- The part I overwritten or modified:

```
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=localhost
nifi.web.https.port=9443
```

- The changed part after re-executing the container:

```
nifi.web.http.host=a8e283ab9421
nifi.web.http.port=9443
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=

#############################################

nifi.web.https.host=a8e283ab9421
nifi.web.https.port=9443
```

I'd like to know how to execute the container with `http.host`, `http.port` empty. `docker-compose.yml` file is as follows:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:  
  nifi:
    build: 
      context: .
      args: 
        NIFI_VERSION: ${NIFI_VERSION}
    container_name: nifi
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - ${NIFI_HTTP_PORT}:8080/tcp
      - ${NIFI_HTTPS_PORT}:9443/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./drivers:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/drivers
      - ./templates:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/templates
      - ./data:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
    environment:
      TZ: 'Asia/Seoul'

      ########## JVM ##########
      NIFI_JVM_HEAP_INIT: ${NIFI_HEAP_INIT} #   The initial JVM heap size.
      NIFI_JVM_HEAP_MAX: ${NIFI_HEAP_MAX} #   The maximum JVM heap size.

      ########## Web ##########
      # NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST: ${NIFI_HTTP_HOST} # nifi.web.http.host
      # NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: ${NIFI_HTTP_PORT} # nifi.web.http.port
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST: ${NIFI_HTTPS_HOST} # nifi.web.https.host
      NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT: ${NIFI_HTTPS_PORT} # nifi.web.https.port
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain your goal.

Comment: @daggett The goal is to run NiFi in a dockerized environment and call `https://localhost:9443/nifi`

Comment: Maybe try switching to NiFi 1.14.0 which has basic security out of the box https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/07/19/apache-nifi-1-14-0-secure-by-default

Comment: @Sdairs Thank you for answer. I'll try to update version to `1.14.0` :)

Comment: @Sdairs It works well. In version `1.14.0`, single user auth can be worked, but not multi user auth. let me know if you know how to use MULTI USER auth as a `1.14.0` version function?

Comment: single user auth is configured by default to give you some credentials to use. If you want multiple users, you need to configure an auth source like LDAP etc.